# Error changing between Nvidia and Intel GPU using Nvidia-settings (no module named 'dbus')

Tags: 16.04, nvidia-prime

I can't change between Nvidia GPU and Intel using sudo nvidia settings. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-prime.py", line 22, in <module>
    import sys, dbus, logging
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'
```

I already tried reinstalling dbus but it did not work.

Comment: How did you go about reinstalling dbus? `sudo apt-get install dbus`? or `sudo apt-get install python-dbus?`

Comment: I have tried both ways and get the same result:
dbus is already the newest version (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3).

python-dbus is already the newest version (1.2.0-3).

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. I stumbled upon a solution.

Try switching GPU using terminal. It does not give an error then.

TO SWITCH TO NVIDIA GPU:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

TO SWITCH TO INTEGRATED INTEL GPU:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Answer (score -2):

You need root privilege to change GPU. Try again with `sudo` from the terminal.

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings
```

Or you can launch the GUI by searching for "NVIDIA X Server Settings" at  the left top Ubuntu button at the toolbar. It will pop up asking you to enter password when you are  trying to change the GPU.

Good luck!